# How to select in date range?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table like:

```
public class Record {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to get something like:

```
[{
    "Date": "StartDate",
    "Records": []
}, {
    "Date": "StartDate+1Day",
    "Records": []
}, {
    "Date": "StartDate+2Day",
    "Records": []
}, {
    "Date": "EndDate",
    "Records": []
}]
```

`StartDate` and `EndDate` would be passed to controller.
`Records` can be null for dates that don't have any records. Is that possible to get something like this using entity framework?

Question is marked as duplicate but I think its not. Currently I'm doing this to get the result I expect:

```
     var dates = new List<DateTime>();
     for (var date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1)) {
        dates.Add(date);
     }

     var report = new List<object>();
     foreach (DateTime date in dates) {
        var item = new {
           Date = date,
           Records = db.Records
           .Where(r => r.Date >= date && r.Date <= date)
           .Select(r => new {
              r.StartTime,
              r.EndTime
           }).ToList()
        };
        report.Add(item);
     }
```

But I think that's not a good way to get the expected result. I just don't know if there's more efficient way to get this result.

Comment: Do you want to select records such that `StartDate` is in between `StartTime` and `EndTime`? Or such that `StartDate` equals `Date`?

Comment: @Paragalor second scenario

Comment: @Reza, you should provide the query you already got as along with the desired result set that you have provided.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat Thanks man :) question updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `DateTime` day equality by using `.Date`:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2019, 7, 18, 12, 5, 2);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2019, 7, 18, 5, 45, 33);
d1.Date == d2.Date
```

As for the data structure you desire, you can create a new class with corresponding properties:

```
public class RecordData
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
}
```

Then, start adding `RecordData` objects to a list:

```
List<RecordData> RecordDatas = new List<RecordData>();
```

Using LINQ statements similar to this (assuming we have list of records from EF named `records` and a start date named `startDate`):

```
RecordDatas.Add(new RecordData
{
    Date: "StartDate",
    Records: records.Where(r => r.Date.Date == startDate.Date).ToList();
}
```

And finally, use a library (such as Newtonsoft Json.NET) to serialize the `RecordData` list to JSON:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RecordDatas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
   public class Record
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        public List<List<Record>> GroupRecords(List<Record> data, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            return data
                .Where(x => (x.Date > start) && (x.Date < end)) 
                .GroupBy(x => x.Date.Date).Select(y => y.ToList()).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's not giving me the expected result. Check the update please.

Comment: There are two reasons you may not get what you are expecting 1) TimeZone of dates 2) I used x,Date.Date which truncates dates to midnight of the start of the day.  Also if start and end are in the middle of a day you may be not be including all the Records on the start/end date.  Some may be you want .Where(x => (x.Date > start.Date) && (x.Date < end.Date.AddDays(1)))